# Can you use L'Hospital for a "$0/\infty$" form as in the case $\lim_{x\to 0} \log(x)/\csc(x)$

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

The original sum was to evaluate 
$$ \lim_{x\to 0} |x|^{\sin(x)}.$$
I converted it into
$$\lim_{x\to 0} \mathrm{e}^{\sin(x)\log|x|}, $$
and then made $\sin x$ as $\csc x$ and shifted to denominator. My friend tells me to use L'Hospital's rule, but as far as I know its used for $0/0$ or $infty/infty$ only. Can this be done without L'Hospital in any way?

Comment: Can you edit your question by [this](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/tex-latex-mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're asking for, but if you end up of a limit that tends to "$\frac 0 {\infty}$", then you're done.  The limit is $0$.  You can see this by taking looking at the ratio as a product instead of a division: i.e. you have $\lim \frac {f(x)}{g(x)} \to \frac 0 {\infty}$ is the same as $\lim f(x) \cdot (\frac 1{g(x)}) \to 0\cdot 0=0$.

Answer (score 1):

You had $|x|^{\sin(x)}$, whose limit is a $0^0$ form. You wrote it as $\exp \left ( \sin(x) \log(|x|) \right )$, which reduces the problem to finding the inner limit, which is a $0 \cdot \infty$ form. You can turn this into a $0/0$ form by writing $\sin(x) \log(|x|) = \frac{\sin(x)}{\frac{1}{\log(|x|)}}$. Similarly you can turn it into a $\infty/\infty$ form by writing $\sin(x) \log(|x|) = \frac{\log(|x|)}{\frac{1}{\sin(x)}}$. In either case you can now use L'Hospital's rule, and then apply $\exp$ to the result. I would suggest computing the left and right limits separately, so that the derivative of the $\log$ term makes sense.

Comment: In the  ∞/∞ form you have described, i didn't get how the numerator is  ∞. Is log(|x|)=∞? If so, how?

Comment: @Aman As $x \to 0$, $\log(|x|) \to -\infty$. This is just a manifestation of the fact that as $x \to -\infty$, $e^x \to 0$. Note that you have to be careful about left and right limits here, because $1/\sin(x) \to -\infty$ from the left and $+\infty$ from the right, and because $x<0$ and $x>0$ give different expressions for the derivative of $\log(|x|)$.

Comment: Okay I got it now :D

Answer (score 0):

It can be done if, and only if, you can prove that
$$
\lim_{x \to 0} x \log x=0
$$
without using De l'Hospital. Can you?

By the way, it is possible, and many analysis books prove this by switching to exponentials, then to sequences, taking integer parts, and using some binomial expansion. I've always thought this approach is elementary but somehow hard to follow.